# Python XML findall is returning the wrong thing

Tags: python, xml, parent-child, findall

I want to read data from an xml file, but its not returning the right thing.
i get only the first of the child nodes instead of all of them

The XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<medicalData>
        <pacijent>         #patient1
            <lbo>12345678901</lbo>
            <ime>bob</ime>
            <prezime>smith</prezime>
            <datumRodj>13.10.1954.</datumRodj>
            <pregledi>nema</pregledi>
        </pacijent>
        <pacijent>          #patient2
            <lbo>22345678901</lbo>
            <ime>bobert</ime>
            <prezime>smith</prezime>
            <datumRodj>30.03.2003</datumRodj>
            <pregledi>nema</pregledi>
        </pacijent>

        <lekar>
            <id>111</id>
            <ime>john</ime>
            <prezime>doe</prezime>
            <spacijalizacija>aaa</spacijalizacija>
        </lekar>
</medicalData>
```

Here, if i search for a patient like:

```
d = etree.parse("pacijent.xml")
listaPodataka = d.getroot()
pacijenti = {}
p = []
for podatak in listaPodataka.findall('pacijent'):
      p.append(podatak)
      for pacijent in p:
      lbo=pacijent[0].text
      ime = pacijent[1].text
      prezime = pacijent[2].text
      datumRodjenja = pacijent[3].text
      pregledi=pacijent[4].text


      pacijenti[lbo]=Pacijent(lbo,ime,prezime,datumRodjenja,pregledi)
return pacijenti
```

it would return patient1 but not patient 2

Any ideas what i am doing wrong? I have tried different solutions but nothing seems to work (from the things i have tried).

Comment: It could be due to the indentation of your code, specifically the `return` statement.  `return` exits the function immediately, so if you have a `return` inside a loop, the loop will only run once.  The indentation in your post is not correct -- please edit the question to fix the indentation.

Comment: that was just in the question, not in the actual code, i edited it now @JohnGordon

Comment: The indentation is still wrong.  The line(s) underneath `for pacijent in p:` are not indented, which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here (56605102.xml is the XML taken from you post)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("56605102.xml")

for pacijent in root.findall('pacijent'):
    print(pacijent)
    for child in pacijent:
        print('\t' + child.tag + ':' + child.text)
```

output

```
<Element 'pacijent' at 0x108d70d68>
    lbo:12345678901
    ime:bob
    prezime:smith
    datumRodj:13.10.1954.
    pregledi:nema
<Element 'pacijent' at 0x108f50868>
    lbo:22345678901
    ime:bobert
    prezime:smith
    datumRodj:30.03.2003
    pregledi:nema
```